# Scala: Inspect bytecode on JVM 1.7 from SBT or Eclipse Scala IDE

Tags: scala, sbt, java-7, bytecode

I looking for a way to inspect the generated bytecode which easily integrates into either SBT or the Eclipse Scala IDE.

I guess the default approach would be to:

- enter `console` in SBT
- run `:javap -c ClassToAnalyze`

However, I'm working on JVM version 1.7 (Scala version 2.10.0) and I simply get:

```
:javap not yet working with java 1.7
```

Are there any alternatives to inspect/analyze the generated bytecode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the following work for me with java 1.7

- `:javap` in the Scala 2.11 REPL
- the `javap` tool of the Java 1.7 JDK

Now, to integrate that with SBT or Eclipse, you could make use of the JDK's `javap` in the same way as any other executable compatible with the command-line.

**EDIT** running external commands is not cross-platform of course, but in the case of SBT "scripts" you can refer to:

- http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Process.html
- http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/index.html#sbt.Process$

Comment: Oh, indeed, running `javap` from the command line works! I don't fully understand your remark regarding the integration to SBT. Can I somehow use JDK's `javap` from within SBT?

Comment: Ok, I guess that this integration is not quite what I expected (eg. autocompletion for class names etc), but I will simply revert to basic Linux features to interact with `javap`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago I put together a simple sbt plugin that dumps the output of the ASM textifier to disk for a whole project, which you might find more convenient than javap.

https://github.com/hcoles/sbt-bytecode

Comment: This is looking very interesting. This was probably developed for SBT 0.11, right? Does it work with recent SBT versions as well?

Comment: @bluenote10 yes probably 0.11 (wrote it a while ago), but should work fine with 0.13. If I get chance I'll turn it into an autoplugin and release it.